# How can I create a complex custom number format for a field in a table in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to combine a complex number format which represents 3 sets of information.  The company which is requesting this database has a Assembly job form with a Job number which is a composite type of Year + Month + version

e.g. 2013/03-03   so the 03 is an incremented version number. 01-999

I have set the custom format as 0000/00-00

But how do I access the individual components of the number when creating a new job or even validate this number using rules. I want the form to create a new incremented job version number when the assembler creates a new job.

so 2013/03/-04

By the way this number is unique and is a primary key.

**Update (Solved workaround)**

> The solution was to split the Job number into atomized fields, this
>   mean't that I could apply individual validation rules to each company.
>   Thanks Alistair for your suggestion.

Comment: I think you need to split this into to fields for incrementing. If you just need to access it via VBA then you could use `left`,`right`,`split` assuming the formatting is consistent

Comment: I would suggest going back to basics of figuring out the fundamentals of DB design. You need to Normalize your tables. For getting something like this, you should be using some concept of DMax+1 (http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=221597)